# How can I implement Drag and Drop (Shuffling of rows) in Datatable of primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using Primefaces DataTable to display content in a grid. I want to reorder these rows using drag and drop(shuffle), I have tried jquery sortable, it works only ones, after that I need to refresh the browser. 
Is there any way to implement that?

Thanks a lot

Comment: as far as i know there is no component like this. you can use sortable data table http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableSorting.jsf

Comment: You will find solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940993/drag-and-drop-of-rows-primefaces-datatable-datagrid/21464068#21464068

Answer (score 3):

This feature is now available from PrimeFaces 5.0:

> Usage is very simple by just enabling draggableRows option and also an optional rowReorder ajax behavior is provided getting a ReorderEvent with index information for flexibility.

Source : http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=3026

You can also have a look at the showcase here: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/reorder.xhtml

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to have row-sorting with server side effects. You can achieve client side reordering using jQuery, but this is not stored on the server.

```
$('.ui-datatable tbody').sortable();
```

There is [a discussion on the PrimeFaces forum](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2678).

There is also [an issue about drag/drop capability in PrimeFaces' issue tracker.](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=564) Note that the issue is closed as WontFix, so I guess you're out of luck.

Comment: @ManojKumar I know, but that's the only solution. I suggest you read my answer more carefully and click on the links I posted.